# How to capture/intercept web page's console log in a my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I know there are 3 different contexts : **background**, **popup**, **web page**. I want to capture/intercept a **web page**'s console log in my extension, How can I do that?

Here is my code:

contentScript.js:

```
    console.log('starting>>>>');

    var log = console.log;
    
    console.log = function () { 
        log.call(this, '**** MY Console**** ');
        log.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        // ...
        }
    };
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "my extension 01",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "----",

    "permissions": ["activeTab","storage","declarativeContent"],
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"],
        "persistent":false
    },
    "page_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "options_page": "options.html",

    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://MY-WEBSITE/*"],
        "run_at":"document_start",
        "js": ["contentScript.js"]
      }
    ],

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](/a/9517879)

Comment: @wOxxOm I just updated my answer, but my Log Interceptor doesn't work!

Comment: There's nothing in your question's code that's related to the answer I've linked so it looks like you didn't actually read it.

Comment: It doesn't relate to the question you mentioned

Comment: Indeed your current code doesn't relate but if you want to solve the problem it should relate :-) In short, your code should run a level deeper, as shown in that answer.

Comment: In the above solution (injecting myscript.js into the web page), I can't get the `extension's options`! (Storage.api)

Comment: Should I use MessagePassing or something else?

Comment: Yep, use CustomEvent messaging, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198).